# Why does my calculator doesn't work, I write it in C

Tags: c

I try to use pointer in this code. but it doesnt work it should be

```
     #include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void scan_data(char sign, float num);
float do_next_op( float num, float* sum);

int main()
{
    printf("Press enter");
    scan_data('x',1);
    return 0;
}
void scan_data(char sign, float num)
{
    char op, symbol;
    float sum;
    sum = 0;

    while (op!='q'||op!='Q') {
     scanf("%c", &symbol);
        printf("Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)\n");
        scanf("%c", &op);

        if(op=='q'||op=='Q')
        {
            printf("The final result is %1.2f\n", sum);
            exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Enter a number to calculate for: ");
            scanf("%f", &num);
            printf("%c%1.2f\n",op, num);
            sum =do_next_op(num, &sum);
        }

}
}


float do_next_op(float num, float* sum)
{


    switch('x')
    {


        case('+'):

            *sum= *sum+num;
            printf("The result so far is %1.2f\n", sum);

            return *sum;
    }
}
```

My exercise is to make a simple calculator that can calculat these operators + - * / and ^. Every time I give a program a number and an operator then it will give me a result then stores a previous result and continue calculate number and an operator until i press q .

This is how it would look like.

```
 Enter operator, and an optional operand: + 5.000000 
Result so far is 5.000000. 
Enter operator, and an optional operand: - 6.000000 
Result so far is -1.000000.
 Enter operator and an optional operand: * 3.000000
 Result so far is -3.000000. 
Enter operator, and an optional operand: q
Final result is: 0.083333
and here is my code which doesn't work
```

ths code can run but it doesn't store the value of operand.
here is a convo between me and the program

```
  Press enter
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)
+
Enter a number to calculate for: 5
+5.00
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)
+
Enter a number to calculate for: 5
+5.00
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)
```

It doesn't print this code `"printf("The result so far is %1.2f\n", sum);"` why?

Comment: 1) The code you posted doesn't seem to be complete.  Please be sure to post code that can successfully compile and run. 2) `switch('x')` doesn't seem right 3) `sum= &sum+num;` doesn't seem right either.  4) Q: are you getting a *compile* error or a *runtime* error???  5) Please update your post, and copy/paste the *EXACT ERROR MESSAGE*.

Comment: change [ sum= &sum+num; ] to [ *sum = *sum + num; ] to fix that error

Comment: In function `do_next_op()`, parameter `sum` is a `float *`.  To access the value that `sum` points to you must use the unary `*` operator: `*sum = *sum + num`, for example.

Comment: @FoggyDay   what does i have to change on  switch('x')?.
my error is  just invalid operands to binary + (have 'float *' and 'float')

c

Comment: @vmp   It works but i still have problem.  here is the convo when i run the program.

Press enter
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)
+
Enter a number to calculate for: 5
+5.00
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)
+
Enter a number to calculate for: 5
+5.00
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)
 


The problem is it doesn't give 10 like i want. why?

Comment: @JohnBollinger

 It works but i still have problem. here is the convo when i run the program. Press enter Enter an operator [^,,/,+,-, q(quit) + Enter a number to calculate for: 5 +5.00 Enter an operator [^,,/,+,-, q(quit) + Enter a number to calculate for: 5 +5.00 Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit) The problem is it doesn't give 10 like i want. why?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: @Bon Prasertsuwan - there were many things wrong with the code you posted - including the fact that it's incomplete, it CANNOT compile as-is. switch() statements generally take a *VARIABLE* (e.g. `op`), not a constant (`'x'`).  Think about it: what's the point of having a case block if only one case is ever true?!? Please follow Basile Starynkevitch's advice: learn to use your debugger.  And please "upvote" and "accept" Khaled Gaber's response if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have multiple issues

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* you included a library header you dont use */

void scan_data(char sign, float num);
/* pass symbol char to do_next_op so you can test which symbol was 
entered and test against in the function */
float do_next_op( float num, float* sum, char symbol);

int main()
{
    printf("Press enter");
    scan_data('x',1);
    return 0;
}
void scan_data(char sign, float num)
{
    char op, symbol;
    float sum;
    sum = 0;

    while (op!='q'||op!='Q') {
        scanf("%c", &symbol);
        printf("Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)] ");
        scanf("%c", &op);

        if(op=='q'||op=='Q')
        {
            printf("The final result is %1.2f\n", sum);
            exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Enter a number to calculate for: ");
            scanf("%f", &num);
            printf("you eneterd symbol: %c and number is:%1.2f\n",op, num);
            sum += do_next_op(num, &sum, symbol);
   /* sum is a cumlative operation use += not = */
        }
    }
}

float do_next_op(float num, float* sum, char symbol) {
 /*  you use switch statment with a char which i dont know why or how it can be used use if statements instead to see which symbol entered 
as a result pass symbol to do_next_op function */
    if (symbol == '+') {
/* also use += instead of = as sum is cumaltive process you don't want to overwrite previous result */
/* also dereference pointer first as function is accepting pointers to floats not floats itself 
dereference is done by * not &(this give address not value pointed by address)*/
        *sum += (*sum + num);
        printf("The result so far is %1.2f\n", sum);
        return *sum;
    }
}
```

I tried to mark up some mistakes in the code so you can know it's place. a little note that output (sum) is showed when you exit only as code you posted and code only deal with `+` operations

Comment: Thank you for helping  but when I run this code it doesn't calculate the previous result  unless i press q to end the loop like this

Press enter
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)] +
Enter a number to calculate for: 5
you eneterd symbol: + and number is:5.00
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)] +
Enter a number to calculate for: 5
you eneterd symbol: + and number is:5.00
Enter an operator [^,*,/,+,-, q(quit)] q
The final result is 10.00

Comment: @BonPrasertsuwan this can be added by a simple ```printf``` after you call ```do_next_op``` in ```main``` I didn't want to add since i tried to focus on mistakes not improvements but it's a simple fix anyway .use ```printf("sum now is: %f\n", sum); ``` place it after ```sum += do_next_op(num, &sum, symbol); ```